# No Bundle URL Present Error

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Getting no bundle error while trying to run react-native app on iOS device.

I created a sample app which works on the simulator, but when i try to run on the device i get the No Bundle Error.

[NO Bundle URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsxnq.jpg)

i tried various options like,

1. Editing the info.plist for NSAllowsLocalNetworking
2. ran npm-install again and linking

but nothing works. I am not able to figure out where the problem arises

Comment: Have you tried deleting the iOS build and re-run the project?

Comment: yes i tried that also, but still having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding `127.0.0.1 localhost` to `/etc/hosts`.
Please check if you have such line there.

Answer (score 1):

Its a simple solution

1. Go to iOS folder
2. Delete the build folder
3. Re run the project from root directory of project 'react-native run-ios'

It will work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I was able to bypass it by run `npm start` before run `react-native run-ios`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running the application directly from the Xcode, also follow the below steps:-

1. For now, disable "Debug JS Remotely".
2. Also, go in the project directory and run "npm start" or "react-native start" command on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

**I know its an old question but in Future if someone face this issue i have found a work around to this problem.**

1. after running "react-native run-ios" command
2. Run another command "npm start"
3. after running above command you will "Loading dependency graph" wait for 2 or three seconds and you will see this**Loading dependency graph, done.**
4. now press cmd+R **OR** you may tap on reload on screen if problem not solved do step 4 2.. to 3 times